# How to rotate the position of an object based on mouse position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm using this code at the moment to rotate a tank turret object towards the mouse position:

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit;
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, range);
Vector3 dir = hit.point - transform.position;
Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
Vector3 rotation = lookRotation.eulerAngles;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotation.y, 0f);
```

Is there any way to create a rotation even when the ray doesn't hit any object, (pointing the mouse where there is no object initiated) (hit is false)? Also is there a better approach for a better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I just get the position of the mouse on screen, compare it to the target object, convert that to degrees, and rotate the object around the wanted axis (Y for topDown 3D space, Z for 2D).

```
void RotateTowards()
    {
        var mouse = Input.mousePosition;
        var screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(tankTransform.localPosition);
        var offset = new Vector2(mouse.x - screenPoint.x, mouse.y - screenPoint.y);
        var angle = Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
    }
```